# Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) and eqnarray

Tags: warnings

I know that the recommended way to suppress messages such

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 23--26
```

is not to use `\\` or `\newline` but instead other methods such as `\medskip`.

My problem is that in lines 23--26 there is an `eqnarray` and I separate equations using `\\` (that seems to cause the above message) ... even though this message does not affect my work (the books is printed correctly) I am curious regarding its origin ... thanks a lot !!

Here is the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray*}
\bm{A}=\bm{A}_{m\times n}=\left(\begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
$\bm{\alpha_{11}}$&$\alpha_{12}$&$\alpha_{13}$&$\dots$&$\alpha_{1j}$&$\dots$&$\alpha_{1n}$\\
$\alpha_{21}$&$\bm{\alpha_{22}}$&$\alpha_{23}$&$\dots$&$\alpha_{2j}$&$\dots$&$\alpha_{2n}$\\
$\alpha_{31}$&$\alpha_{32}$&$\bm{\alpha_{33}}$&$\dots$&$\alpha_{3j}$&$\dots$&$\alpha_{3n}$\\
$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\bm{\ddots}$&$\vdots$&$\ddots$&$\vdots$\\
$\alpha_{i1}$&$\alpha_{i2}$&$\alpha_{i3}$&$\ddots$&$\bm{\alpha_{ij}}$&$\ddots$&$\alpha_{in}$\\
$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\vdots$&$\ddots$&$\vdots$&$\bm{\ddots}$&$\vdots$\\
$\alpha_{m1}$&$\alpha_{m2}$&$\alpha_{m3}$&$\dots$&$\alpha_{mj}$&$\dots$&$\bm{    \alpha_{mn}}$\\
\end{tabular}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

it just prints an $n\times n$ array. The code extends from line 20 to line 30 and the message refers to the lines 23--26.

Comment: you mean `\\ ` not `//` I assume. the `\\ ` in an eqnarray are unlikely to generate this message, please show a small complete document that shows the problem. Note that `eqnarray` is deprecated and it is much better to use `align` from the amsmath package, but `align` rows similarly end with `\\ `

Comment: do you have the `\\ ` after the environment as in `\end{eqnarray}\\ ` ?

Comment: yes i mean \\ of cource (i made a mistake) .. the code segment is

Comment: yes i mean \\ of cource (i made a typing mistake) .. no, there is not an \\ after eqnarray .... the codei mention  just prints out a 3x3 matrix and in order to do this, i use the tabular environment inside the equation array (where in fact i use the \\) .. i suppose that the \\ put in an eqnarray does not cause the 'Underfull hbox...' message ... yes i know the align package and i will use it in the future .. thanks a lot

Comment: sorry unless you put a small example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` into your question it will be impossible to guess what you did or how to fix your document not to have the warning.

Comment: as I said, the example should be a complete document that makes the warning, I took your fragment and added bm and `\documentclass` so it could be tested but it makes no warnings. The markup is rather odd, you should not be using `tabular` here but `array` for math mode, but that is a separate issue. Please edit the question so the example makes the underfull box warning.

Comment: are you sure that the "line 23" was line 23 of your main file (not for example line 23 of your table of contents)

Comment: i made the same thought and i am looking for this right now ... i will inform you about the result .. since your test did not produce any error maybe the problem is at another file .... thanks again for your time

Comment: yes, the problem found in the file cover.tex where i have the code for the book cover and in order to put some vertical space between the book title and the author name i wrote

    ${}$\\${}$\\${}$\\${}$\\${}$\\
    ${}$\\${}$\\${}$\\${}$\\${}$\\
    ${}$\\${}$\\${}$\\${}$\\${}$\\

now i replaced these lines with the command \vspace{5cm} and the problem solved .. i confused by the log file since i have not much experience in its use and that's why i reached the above (erroneous) conclusion .... your help and interest is greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: i'm voting to close this question since the problem was in a different file than the one originally reported. the problem has been solved as noted in comments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as barbara said

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was in a different file than the one reported, and it has been solved as noted in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not produce any `Underfull \hbox` warning. However, you should modify it to make it easier to type.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\bm{A}=\bm{A}_{m\times n}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\bm{\alpha_{11}}&\alpha_{12}&\alpha_{13}&\dots&\alpha_{1j}&\dots&\alpha_{1n}\\
\alpha_{21}&\bm{\alpha_{22}}&\alpha_{23}&\dots&\alpha_{2j}&\dots&\alpha_{2n}\\
\alpha_{31}&\alpha_{32}&\bm{\alpha_{33}}&\dots&\alpha_{3j}&\dots&\alpha_{3n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\bm{\ddots}&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
\alpha_{i1}&\alpha_{i2}&\alpha_{i3}&\dots&\bm{\alpha_{ij}}&\dots&\alpha_{in}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\bm{\ddots}&\vdots\\
\alpha_{m1}&\alpha_{m2}&\alpha_{m3}&\dots&\alpha_{mj}&\dots&\bm{\alpha_{mn}}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The changes I made are:

1. loading of `amsmath`
2. usage of `equation*` instead of `eqnarray*` (see [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196))
3. `pmatrix` instead of `tabular`
4. `\dots` instead of `\ddots` in row *i*

About 2, note that `eqnarray` should not be used and `amsmath` environments should be preferred. Also, avoid using a multiline display for a single equation.

About 3, recall that `array` is the analog of `tabular` for math mode and doesn't require to input each cell as a math formula (`pmatrix` is based on it).

Your last comment should also be analyzed: using `\\` for vertical space is definitely not the best way to cope with the problem.

[image]

Comment: Dear Sir i will implement all of your suggestions .. thanks a lot !! Athanasios